# Apache hangs or is extremely slow for some user

Tags: php, apache-2.2, response-time

we have a local apache 2.2.3 server on CentOS running a local PHP website. About half of the office is able to load the php pages the others will wait for about 1 minute or longer before the server will respond. When the response finally arrive the user is not able to interact with the page. It is like its totally dead.

Restarting apache is no help. 
Changing browsers does not help either.
apache error_log and access_log does not show anything in particular.

I really have no idea where to look for a solution for this issue.

**UPDATE:** I found out the apache has no issue displaying normal html pages for these users. It is only php pages.

Comment: This does not belong on StackOverflow, someone move it please (to serverfault)

Comment: Check the apache error logs- what is the difference between the users? Are you SURE they are hitting the same server? Have the users got some cache (either local/server) hence why it's working for them?

Comment: These users are using the exact same url. The error logs does not display any error. The access log will show that the users have had access cause eventually they get the response. The browser cache should not be a problem since some of the user have never visited this particular URL nor has some of the users where it works.

Comment: user590696 - please put your comment in your question as an answer, and then accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that xdebug was causing this issue. I removed the xdebug from the server and from php.ini and **BOOOM**. Everything was working fine for all users.